# knockout.js accessing container model property in a contained viewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have nested view models like below.  I am trying to access value in container view model from the contained view model (child).  I got undefined error when the modelA.prop1 trying to get mainVM.prop1 value.  Thanks for your help.

```
function mainVM() {

    var self = this;

    //chain associated view models
    self.modelA = new modelA();
    self.modelB = new modelB();

    self.prop1 = ko.observable("some value from mainVM.prop1");

}
function modelA(){
   var self = this;
   self.prop1 = ko.observable(mainVM.prop1); //I'd like to get value in containing view model above
}
function modelB(){....}

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new mainVM();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sub-ViewModels dependent/aware of their parent you'll have to pass it to them. E.g.:

```
function mainVM() {
    var self = this;

    //chain associated view models
    self.modelA = new modelA(self);
    self.modelB = new modelB(self);

    self.prop1 = ko.observable("some value from mainVM.prop1");

}
function modelA(parent){
   var self = this;
   self.prop1 = ko.observable(parent.prop1); //I'd like to get value in containing view model above
}
function modelB(parent){....}

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new mainVM();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Think carefully though if this dependency is something you want in your design.

An alternative (though arguably worse from a design standpoint) solution would be to give them access through the scope, e.g.:

```
$(function () {
    function mainVM() {
        var self = this;

        //chain associated view models
        self.modelA = new modelA();
        self.modelB = new modelB();

        self.prop1 = ko.observable("some value from mainVM.prop1");

    }
    function modelA(){
       var self = this;
       self.prop1 = ko.observable(viewModel.prop1); //I'd like to get value in containing view model above
    }
    function modelB(){....}

    var viewModel = new mainVM();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additional thoughts to @Jeroen answer

Having dependencies to parent from children is not only bad design it can create hard to find memory leaks

If you use the parent from a computed in the child KO will hook up a dependency, if you remove the child it's computed will still fire when the parent change state.

My general way of solving dependencies between models is to use a EventAggregator pattern, I have made one for this library

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Its a signalR library, if you do not need singalR you can extract the event aggregation part

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/jh8JV/

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.events = ko.observableArray();
    this.subModel = new SubViewModel();

    signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(Event, this.onEvent, this);
};

ViewModel.prototype = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
        this.events.push(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got an "XY problem" here: you want to accomplish task X (which you haven't named here) and you think that implementation Y (in this case, a child VM having a dependency on its parent) is the way to do it, even though Y might not be the best (or even a good) way to do it.

What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? If you need to access the parent property from within a child binding, Knockout's binding context ($root, $parent, $parents[], etc.) will let you do it, e.g.

```
<div data-bind="with:modelA">
   <p>prop2 is <span data-bind="text:prop2"></span>
      and prop1 from the main model is
      <span data-bind="text:$root.prop1"></span>
   </p>
</div>
```

In this case you could use `$parent` in place of `$root` since there's only one level of nesting.